# Bitcoin Mining -> A mining pool that pays in USD (preferred) or BTC per Unit Time per CPU rate

Tags: mining-pools

I plan on mining bitcoin, and I would like to know a good mining pool that pays in USD per Unit Time per CPU rate (preferred) or BTC per Unit Time per GPU/ASIC rate.

I would like to know 
1. The highest rate for such a pool in USD or BTC, and
2. The highest rate for such a pool in USD (direct USD payment)

I know such a pool exists, I just need names. If you do not think such a pool exists, I would like to know of a pool with a high success rate or with lots of power as to provide a near steady income. Thank you for any and all answers

[EDIT] for CPU to GPU or ASIC

Comment: Except for the payment in USD, how is this any different from all mining pools?

Comment: Or are you asking for current values of mining profitability?

Comment: it would be a more effective money making method going to your nearest town and searching for pennies on the ground, just saying.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't mine with CPU.
2. All mining pools pay BTC. They all pay pretty similar.
3. You won't get any income. 0 with CPU or less than your electricity cost if you have better hardware. Only people that really know what they are doing AND can pay for the latest hardware in decent quantities (without getting scammed by the manufacturer) AND have access to large amounts of cheap electricity will be able to earn a bit of income.